# get page content using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I would like to scrape the content of this
http://whostreams.net/embed/gryr4u074z82x using curl. 
I've been trying setting different user agents, and setting other options 
but I just can't seem to get the content of that page, as I often get redirected or I get a "page moved" error.
I believe it has something to do with the fact that the query string gets encoded somewhere but I'm really not sure how to get around that.

```
$url = 'http://whostreams.net/embed/gryr4u074z82x';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.fel3arda.com/2018/09/denmark-vs-wales.html');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: whostreams.net'));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo ($query) ;
```

What do I need to do to get my php code to show the exact content of the page

Comment: Is this your link `http://whostreams.net/embed/gryr4u074z82x`  or  is this your link `http://whostreams.net`

Comment: voted to close this, because the code returns the HTML.

Comment: If your link is `http://whostreams.net` ... Its works fine.

Comment: @A.ANoman i can not understand but i need to get content this link
http://whostreams.net/embed/gryr4u074z82x

Comment: @amrselim First check your  `http://whostreams.net/embed/gryr4u074z82x`  link access

Comment: its only open like iframe on this site 
http://www.fel3arda.com/2018/09/denmark-vs-wales.html

Comment: @amrselim can you [contact me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik?tab=profile) when you have time? i want to show you what your browser and what your curl request really receives, and how to see it for yourself, should only take 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

curl_exec() need to be before curl_close();

Because curl_close() Terminates the CURL session and releases resources. The descriptor curl_handle is also destroyed.

Comment: echo before curl_close()

Comment: @SlavikPastushenko already use it
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
echo ($query) ;
curl_close($curl_handle);

but its same . redirec to new page

Comment: @Phil there is redirect from http://whostreams.net/embed/gryr4u074z82x to http://whostreams.net

Comment: Why is everyone replying to me?

Answer (score 0):

the code you posted works for me, just added a `<?php` to it.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://whostreams.net/embed/gryr4u074z82x';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.fel3arda.com/2018/09/denmark-vs-wales.html');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: whostreams.net'));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo ($query) ;
```

i do indeed get the

```
CLICK HERE TO UNMUTE

STREAM IS OFFLINE
Retrying in seconds
```

page + the heavily obfuscated javascript used to start streaming the video from wss://ws.peer5.com

you say `I just can't seem to get the content of that page` - well, what content are you getting? and what did you expect to get instead? because here is roughly what my Google Chrome webbrowser and curl is getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<script>if(window==window.top) document.location="/"</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/embed.min.css?v=0.1" />
<!-- Tssp-->
<!-- PopAds.net Popunder Code for whostreams.net | 2018-09-09,2437207,0,0 -->
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">
/*<![CDATA[/* */
/* Generated 2018-09-09 16:26:49 for "PopAds%20CGAPIL%20A", len 1367 */
 (function(){ var p=window;p["\x5f\x70\x6fp"]=[["\u0073i\x74e\u0049\x64",2437207],["\u006d\x69\x6e\u0042i\x64",0],["\x70\x6f\u0070un\x64er\x73Pe\x72\x49\x50",0],["\x64\x65\u006c\u0061y\u0042e\x74\u0077een",0],["\u0064\x65\u0066\u0061u\u006ct",false],["\x64\u0065fau\x6c\x74P\x65\u0072\x44a\u0079",0],["\u0074o\u0070\x6dos\x74\x4cay\x65\x72",!1]];var l=["/\x2fc\u0031\x2ep\x6f\u0070a\u0064s\u002en\x65\u0074\u002f\x70o\x70\u002e\u006a\u0073","/\u002f\x63\u0032.p\x6fpa\x64\u0073.n\x65t/\x70\u006fp\u002ej\x73","//w\x77\x77.\x6b\u0061\u006f\x6ariv\u006d\u0068\x79s\x2ec\u006f\x6d\u002f\u0062p\x2ejs","/\x2fww\x77.\x74djo\x61\x6f\x73\u0069\u0062\x65\x73\u002e\x63om\x2f\x78\u002ejs",""],w=0,x,a=function(){if(""==l[w])return;x=p["\u0064\x6f\u0063\u0075\u006de\u006e\u0074"]["\x63\u0072e\x61\x74\u0065\u0045le\u006d\x65n\x74"]("\x73cr\u0069\x70\x74");x["\x74\x79\x70\u0065"]="te\x78\x74\u002f\u006a\x61v\x61\u0073\u0063\x72\x69p\u0074";x["\x61\x73\u0079\u006ec"]=!0;var s=p["\x64\x6fcu\u006de\x6et"]["g\u0065\u0074Ele\x6d\x65n\x74\x73\x42\u0079\x54\x61\x67\u004ea\x6d\x65"]("\x73\u0063r\u0069\u0070\u0074")[0];x["\x73\x72c"]=l[w];if(w<2){x["\u0063ro\u0073\x73Or\u0069g\x69\u006e"]="\x61\x6eo\u006e\x79mo\x75s";};x["\u006f\u006ee\x72\x72\u006f\u0072"]=function(){w++;a()};s["p\x61\x72\u0065n\u0074\u004e\u006f\x64\u0065"]["\u0069nse\x72\x74\x42\x65\x66ore"](x,s)};a()})();
/*]]>/* */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jwplayer jw-reset jw-skin-glow" id="player"></div>
<div id="btn-unmute" onclick="WSUnmute()">CLICK HERE TO UNMUTE</div>
<div class="tb stream-offline" >
  <div class="tb-col">
    <a href="/" target="_blank"><img src="/imgs/logo.png" /></a>
    <h2>STREAM IS OFFLINE</h2>
    <p>Retrying in <span class="counter"></span> seconds</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var WSreloadCounter,WSnTries=0,videoStarted = false, startMuted = startMuted();function errorPlaying(){$(".stream-offline .counter").text(10);$(".stream-offline").css("display","table");WSreloadCounter=setInterval(function(){var a=$(".stream-offline .counter").text();if(a>1){a--;$(".stream-offline .counter").text(a)}else{ clearInterval(WSreloadCounter);WSnTries++;if(WSnTries<10){WSreloadStream();}else{ window.location.reload() } }},1000)}function startMuted(){var d=/constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement)||(function(a){return a.toString()==="[object SafariRemoteNotification]"})(!window.safari||(typeof safari!=="undefined"&&safari.pushNotification));if(d){return true}var c=!!window.chrome&&!!window.chrome.webstore;if(c&&getChromeVersion()>=66){return true}return false}function getChromeVersion(){var a=navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);return a?parseInt(a[2],10):false};</script>

<script src="//api.peer5.com/peer5.js?id=5yaksk6z3h8drz14s022"></script><script src="//api.peer5.com/peer5.clappr.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="/players/clappr/clappr.min.js?v=0.22"></script>
<script>eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('6 3;$(4).J(2(){3=C D.E({K:"L://Y.l.k:10/V/H.17?s=-Z&e=W",X:"#3",11:"r%",12:"r%",14:q,13:q,U:"M",I:"",N:"1",O:"",T:{S:2(e){R()},P:2(e){5(2(){$(".9-B").G()},Q);16(!p){p=8;5(2(){6 h=4.o("t")[0],s=4.u("x");s.w("n-v","y.b");s.f="z/d";s.m=8;s.g="//1o.b/1n/18/1l/1q.j";h.i(s)},F);5(2(){6 h=4.o("t")[0],s=4.u("x");s.w("n-v","y.b");s.f="z/d";s.m=8;s.g="//l.k/1i/1h.j";h.i(s)},1g);5(2(){$.1m("",{"1f":"H","a":"A"})},F)}},1e:2(e){$(".9-B").1d()},19:2(e){$("#1a-c").G()},}})});2 1b(){$(".9-1k").1j("1p","1s");6 7=3.1r(3);7=C D.E(7.1t);3.1c();3=7;3.A();3.c()}2 15(){3.c()}',62,92,'||function|player|document|setTimeout|var|newplayer|true|stream||com|unmute|javascript||type|src||appendChild|js|net|whostreams|async|data|getElementsByTagName|videoStarted|false|100||head|createElement|domain|setAttribute|script|aeckcjy|text|play|logo|new|Clappr|Player|15000|fadeOut|gryr4u074z82x|watermark|ready|source|http|bestfit|position|watermarkLink|onPlay|1000|errorPlaying|onError|events|stretching|hls|1536534286|parent|cdn|Xj60CxQUPZV0M5RAeKbFA|8080|width|height|mute|autoPlay|WSUnmute|if|m3u8|d1|onVolumeUpdate|btn|WSreloadStream|destroy|fadeIn|onPause|ref|120000|adcash|pops|css|offline|fa|post|d4|wdaxvjr9dc|display|d4d1faecf77b3799e550953764a305da|configure|none|options'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script><!--Amung / Analytics -->
<div style="display:none;"><img name="viewers" src="//whos.amung.us/cwidget/whostreams/000000ffffff.png"></div>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-112185528-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-112185528-1');
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its redirct me to anther site

Comment: @amrselim check what html your browser actually receives, it's the html above. if you're using chrome, you can check like this: right-click on any page, press "Inspect", go to the "Network" tab, make sure to check the "Preserve Log" button, then paste in the url above. you'll get the HTML above. which includes `<script>if(window==window.top) document.location="/"</script>` - which is a protection against direct loading, this makes web browsers redirect you to the front page if they're NOT in an iframe. but it's still the same HTML received by both your web browser, and curl. if you want to rem

Comment: @amrselim if you want to remove the redirect, you gotta do something like: ```$query = curl_exec($curl_handle); $domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($query);$script=$domd->getElemensByTagName("script")->item(0); $script->parentNode->removeChild($script); $query=$domd->saveHTML(); echo $query;```  - this should be the html without the redirect script.